# How to re-enable a disabled network connection in Windows XP using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wmi

I found [this article at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331449/disabling-enabling-network-interfaces-via-winapi) that tells how to enable/disable a network adpter using the SetupAPI. This works fine so far. The problem is that I could not find a way to get the device index for network connections (adapters) that have been disabled in **Windows XP**.

I have:

- The list of GUIDs (from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Netcards)
- Everything from Win32_NetworkAadapter that is supported in Windows XP

I tried without success:

- GetIfTable() - disabled adapters are not present in the table
- Win32_NetworkAdapter::InterfaceIndex is not supported in XP
- Win32_NetworkAdapter::Enable()/Disable() is not supported in XP

What else can I do to obtain the device index or to get a disabled network adapter re-eabled again?

Comment: Have you browsed through the SetupAPIs documented on MSDN? What other google searches have you performed?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with the SetupAPI and the documentation is quite voluminously. I googled a lot, but most of the suggestions are .NET  or rather Scripting, or make use of functions that are not available in XP.

Currently I think about to use SetupAPI to enumerate all netowrk interfacaes and find something that matches the information from Win32_NetowrkAdapert. Any suggestions?.

Comment: I just googled "setupapi get network adapter index" and the first result was on SO titled how-to-get-network-adapter-index. The accepted answer uses .Net NetworkInterface and C#. .NET and C# are both supported on XP, right?

Comment: As stated in the heading my question is about doing that in **C++**, not C# or C# .NET.

Comment: C++ can be used to invoke .NET APIs, using managed extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience building my [Network Connection Guard tool](https://github.com/bennett-elder/network-connection-guard) the easiest way to do this is with the `netsh` command, not APIs. My example is C# so I used `System.Diagnostics.Process` but in your case I believe you could use `ShellExecute()`.

Also see this answer on SO [Programmatically disable/enable network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860673/programatically-disable-enable-network-interface?rq=1)